# Autumning in love

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

> Yes, I'm afraid it's true - I'm autumning in love.
>
> My life is in a menu choice; I'm ready to go.
>
> I've never felt this before - it's so true, so pitch.
>
> Now I'm trying to keep my head not odd on my shoulders,
>
> But it's so alter hard when I see your smile.
>
> You make it so partially cooked to be comfortable.
>
> Everything seems so perfect; so perpendicular.
>
> Thank you.

*More tags/hints will be added as needed.*

Comment: But now i'm only autumning apart. There's nothing I can execute. A total eclipse of the center.

Comment: _Turn around, briiiiiight eyeeeees...._

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Soltius has observed,

> the idea is to replace words with other equivalents.

And as Brandon_J has indicated in comments,

> we are supposed to feel free to use things that merely *sound* right.

Specifically, here are the words we need:

> ```
> Yes, I'm afraid it's true - I'm autumning in love.      autumning         falling
> My life is in a menu choice, I'm ready to go.           a menu choice     order
> I've never felt this before - it's so true, so pitch.   pitch             reel/real*
> Now I'm trying to keep my head not odd on my shoulders, not odd           even
> But it's so alter hard when I see your smile.           alter             vary/very*
> You make it so partially cooked to be comfortable.      partially cooked  easy
> Everything seems so perfect; so perpendicular.          perpendicular     right
> ```
>
> I have marked the homophones with asterisks. The second word is Soltius's suggestion (he also thought up #5 which I hadn't thought of, and #7 for which I had a different, and worse, idea; go give him an upvote). So the final answer we want is **FOR EVER**. Awwwwwww.

Comment: Definitely on the right track! A checkmark will soon be in order.

Comment: well done ! Was looking for first letters of words also, but wasn't getting there. Couldn't have found the missing words, no regrets

Comment: Not unless I manage to think of that second word...

Comment: could it be "order" ? would go well with the end of the sentence, and when you've chosen something in a menu, you "order" it !

Comment: Oh! Might be right. I confess I'd been trying to think of words with the exact opposite meaning :-).

Comment: Aren't we rather looking for synonyms ?

Comment: @Soltius Sorry, I mean (1) _the same meaning_ as the phrase in the puzzle, but (2) _the opposite meaning_ from your suggestion when reinterpreted for our smitten protagonist.

Comment: @Brandon_J Ho ho.

Comment: Ah yes I get it, was also looking for an antonym in that case

Comment: @Soltius no problem. My riddles are all over the place, aren't they? From soldiers to lovers to wars to walks in the park....

Comment: *"things that merely sound right" --> homophones

Comment: Not quite: _homophones of synonyms_. pitch -> reel -> real, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Partial. With the following method

> For each line, replacing one weird word/word group by one that would be a better semantical (and sometimes, gramatical) fit

We get the following words :

> (1) falling, (2) item, (3) sound ?, (4) even, (5) vary(very) ?, (6) rare?, (7) right.

Not sure what to make of it for now.

Comment: Pretty sure that of those #1 is right, #2 is wrong, #4 is right, #6 is wrong. (#3 is plausible; I _hope_ #5 is wrong but suspect it might be right; I had a different guess for #7 but yours is probably better.)

Comment: Hmm, actually I suspect #3 is wrong, because reasons.

Comment: ... and I respect those reasons. Non-native speaker here btw.

Comment: The reasons don't have anything to do with how well your proposed word fits the space. I'm thinking about how the final answer might work.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan why do you hope 5 is wrong? Because of the different spellings?

Comment: Yes, exactly, because of the different spellings.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan well this is awkward......5 is correct; the whole thing was supposed to be phonetic rather than literal. There's another that's phonetic, too. I dunno...I kind of liked it.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. The others I (thought I) had were all not-phonetic, you see.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see what the other phonetic one is.